# Hinting to Redshift how to distribute a join?

Tags: optimization, redshift, hints

If I am joining between two tables, A and B, with multiple equality constraints, is there any way that I can hint to Redshift which it should use for distributing the join? For example, in:

```
FROM A
JOIN B
  ON  B.id = A.b_id
  AND B.x = some_expression_of(A.x)
```

In my situation, I know that all the data is already distributed by this X expression, so that if Redshift distributes by it, there will not be any actual network activity.

---

Edit: Here's a more representative version of the join:

```
FROM order_products --distribution key: user_id
FULL OUTER JOIN order_payments --distribution key: user_id
   ON FALSE
LEFT JOIN orders --distribution key: user_id
   ON  orders.id = COALESCE(order_products.order_id, order_payments.order_id)
   AND orders.user_id = COALESCE(order_products.user_id, order_payments.user_id)
```

What I'd like is to just be able to tell Redshift to please distribute the last join based on user_id (which Redshift might categorize as a  DS_DIST_BOTH, but should actually result in no network redistribution)

Comment: Interesting use of `full join on false`. You could try rewrite it to a union and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use hints in Redshift like Oracle. You can do things like set the distribution keys. If X is always used in that fashion, it may make sense to incorporate that into your DDL.

See here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Distributing_data.html

Comment: Thanks, distribution keys are already set (and are set to X), but the expression is going to be preferable to having to change the schema

Comment: What is "some_expression_of(A.x)"? Can you pre-calculate that and make it the dist key?

Comment: added a more representative version of the query in the original question